# Customizing a responsive nav menu (Naver)

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm using the [Naver jQuery plugin](http://www.benplum.com/formstone/naver/) to create a responsive navigation menu, and I'm having difficulty achieving the desired layout. [I've set up a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickpish/tuFhT/). I've configured the media query breakpoint at 640 px, and while I want the nav menu floated right in it's "non-mobilized" state, when the plugin is initialized I would like the list items to fill 100% of the header width, with centered text below the "logo" which I would like to persist in the upper left. I'm trying to figure out which layout elements I need to adjust accordingly.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
   nav li {
      float: none;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
   }
}
```

Thanks for any assistance here.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your css with this I think it's what you are looking for.

```
nav {
    width: 100;
}
nav ul {
    display: table;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
}
nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```